# Calculate difference between two subgroups by column with NAs in R

Tags: r, subset, na

I am trying to calculate the absolute difference between two subgroups in a column with NAs in R.  Or more concretely, I am working on a project where I am trying to calculate the degree of partisanship on a legislative roll call vote in R.  Specifically, I am trying to calculate how different Republicans and Democrats vote on a roll-call.  The specific equation I am trying to calculate with my data is the following:

```
Roll Call Partisanship=|Democratic Aye % - GOP Aye %|
```

My data is structured as the following:

```
Legislator   Party   Vote1   Vote2   Vote3  Vote4  Vote5   Vote6   Vote7
Allen           R     yes     no      NA     no     yes     yes     no
Barber          D     NA      no      no     yes    no      yes     no
Cale            D     no      NA      yes    yes    yes     no      yes
Devin           R     no      no      no     yes    yes     yes     yes
Egan            R     yes     yes     yes    NA     no      no      no
Floyd           R     yes     no      yes    no     yes     no      yes
```

Here is the R code to create this table:

```
Legislator=c("Allen", "Barber", "Cale", "Devin", "Egan", "Floyd")
Party=c("R", "D", "D", "R", "R", "R")
vote1=c("yes", "NA", "no", "no", "yes", "yes")
vote2=c("no", "no", "NA", "no", "yes", "no")
vote3=c("NA", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes")
vote4=c("no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "NA", "no")
vote5=c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes")
vote6=c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
vote7=c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes")

rollcall=cbind(Legislator, Party, vote1, vote2, vote3, vote4, vote5, vote6, vote7)
```

Using the equation above, I would like to create a Matrix that looks like the following:

```
RollCall  Partisanship
Vote1     0.75
Vote2     0.25
Vote3     0.17
Vote4     0.70
Vote5     0.25
Vote6     0.00
Vote7     0.00
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might be able to calculate these scores in R?  In particular, I am having trouble with the NAs.  I would like a legislator who didn’t vote on a roll-call to not be included in a particular calculation.  However, if you use na.omit, then that completely takes out the legislator in all roll-call calculations.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
# convert your matrix to a data.table
dt <- data.table(rollcall)
# replace "NA"'s by actual NA's
dt[dt == "NA"] <- NA

# get your data in long format and calculate summary statistics
dt_long <- melt(dt, id.vars = "Party", measure = patterns("^vote"))
dt_long <- dt_long[!is.na(value),.(votes = sum(value=="yes") / .N), .(Party,variable)]

# spread the result to arrive at expected format
dcast(dt_long, variable ~ Party, value.var = "votes")[,.(Partisanship = abs(D - R)), "variable"]
#  variable Partisanship
#1:    vote1    0.7500000
#2:    vote2    0.2500000
#3:    vote3    0.1666667
#4:    vote4    0.6666667
#5:    vote5    0.2500000
#6:    vote6    0.0000000
#7:    vote7    0.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` (uglier than the solution already posted, but spent a lot of time making it so still posting it now):

```r
# setting up the data
# **note that I've changed "NA" entries to NA **

Legislator <- c("Allen", "Barber", "Cale", "Devin", "Egan", "Floyd")
Party <- c("R", "D", "D", "R", "R", "R")
vote1 <- c("yes", NA, "no", "no", "yes", "yes")
vote2 <- c("no", "no", NA, "no", "yes", "no")
vote3 <- c(NA, "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes")
vote4 <- c("no", "yes", "yes", "yes", NA, "no")
vote5 <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes")
vote6 <- c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
vote7 <- c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes")

rollcall <- as.data.frame(base::cbind(Legislator, Party, vote1, vote2, vote3, vote4, vote5, vote6, vote7))

# converting to long format
library(tidyr)
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.4.2
rollcall_long <- tidyr::gather(rollcall, vote, response, vote1:vote7, factor_key = TRUE)

# compute frenquency table
library(dplyr)

vote_frequency <- rollcall_long %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(response)) %>% # remove NAs
  dplyr::group_by(Party, vote, response) %>% # compute frequency by these grouping variables
  dplyr::summarize(counts = n()) %>% # get the count of each response
  dplyr::mutate(perc = counts / sum(counts)) %>% # compute its percentage
  dplyr::arrange(vote, response, Party) %>% # arrange it properly
  dplyr::filter(response == "yes") %>% # select only yes responses ("Ayes")
dplyr::select(-counts, -response)  # remove counts and response variables

# compute Partisanship score
Partisanship_df <- tidyr::spread(vote_frequency, Party, perc)
Partisanship_df[is.na(Partisanship_df)] <- 0 # replacing NA with 0 because NA here represents that not a single "yes" was found
Partisanship_df$Partisanship <- abs(Partisanship_df$D - Partisanship_df$R)

# removing unnecessary columns
Partisanship_df %>% dplyr::select(-c(R, D))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#> # Groups: vote [7]
#>   vote  Partisanship
#> * <fct>        <dbl>
#> 1 vote1        0.750
#> 2 vote2        0.250
#> 3 vote3        0.167
#> 4 vote4        0.667
#> 5 vote5        0.250
#> 6 vote6        0    
#> 7 vote7        0
```

Created on 2018-01-20 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).